# Trying to get a link working inside of a popover

Tags: html, css, popover

I am trying to add a link inside of a popover when you hover over it, but unfortunately, it is not working. I was wondering if someone can see what I am doing wrong?  My approach was adding an a href tag inside of another a tag, but it is not working.  Any guidance is appreciated.

```css
    a:active:after {
        content: attr(title);
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        top: 5px;
        right: 10%;
        background: #bada55;
    }

    a:visited {
        color: green;
    }

    a:hover {
        color: DarkOrchid;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a:active {
        color: yellow;
    }

    .twitter {
        margin: 2em auto 0px auto;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: small;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #f5911d;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    /* SIGNATURE CODE */
    a {
        color: #f77d06;
        -o-transition: color .5s ease-out, background 7s ease-in;
        -ms-transform: color .5s ease-out, background 7s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: color .5s ease-out, background 7s ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: color .5s ease-out, background 7s ease-in;
        transition: color .5s ease-out, background 7s ease-in;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        a:hover {
            color: #FFF;
            background: none;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 text-left">
    <i class="fa m-r-15 text-left" style="font-weight: bold"><a style="color:orangered" data-toggle="popover" title="LEARN MORE" data-content="Want to lear more Check out out definition page by clicking <a href='www.google.com'> here">My Pizza Deliveries</a></i>
</div>
                                    
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
      placement: 'top',
      trigger: 'hover'
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @urvashi it is in the icon class on the html portion of the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Popovers can't contain href or such, they contain plain text according to the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20popover%2C%20add,popover%22%20attribute%20to%20an%20element.&text=Note%3A%20Popovers%20must%20be%20initialized,call%20the%20popover()%20method.). Moreover, the options and possibilities are very limited.

But SO wouldn't be SO if we wouldn't offer an appropriate alternative.

Let me introduce you to [tippy tooltips](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) which is a highly-customizable and very well documentated library for tooltips which in your case can basically be implemented like so:

```js
const template = document.getElementById('example');
template.style.display = 'block';

tippy('#tippy-element', {
  content: template,
  interactive: true,
  interactiveBorder: 60,
});
```

```css
#tippy-element {
    width: 30vw;
}

#example {
   color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Development Tippy tooltip -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6/dist/tippy-bundle.umd.js"></script>

<html>
    <body>

    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 text-left" id="tippy-element">My Pizza Deliveries</div>            
                     
    <a id="example" href="https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/">Click me</a>         
          
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand why you are putting  tag inside another  tag. You just need to put the link inside data-template property.

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 text-left">
  <i class="fa m-r-15 text-left" style="font-weight: bold">
    <a style="color:orangered"
       data-toggle="popover" 
       title="LEARN MORE"
       data-template="<div>Want to lear more Check out out definition page by 
                           clicking 
                           <a href='https://www.google.com/' target='blank'>here</a>
                      </div>">My Pizza Deliveries</a>
  </i>
</div>
```

If you want to add your link dynamically, pls use template property.